# Accessing variable outside while loop C

Tags: c, variables, while-loop

I'm very new to C so please forgive this stupid question. I have this following code that reads the 3rd line from a text file, which is the number 38. I assign this to an int within the while loop, however, I get a different result when accessing this variable outside the while loop. This is my code:

```
int main() {

    FILE* file = fopen("blocks.txt", "r");
    char line[256];
    int number;
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        i++;
        if (i == 3)
        {
            number = line;

            //prints 38
            printf("%s", line);
        }
    }
    //prints something random!
    printf("%d", number);
    fclose(file);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if this is vague, and it will probably get deleted, but please give me some help haha!

Comment: `number` is of type `int` and you are assigning a `char*` to it without a proper cast.

Comment: Did you change the code after you posted it? I could have sworn outside the `while` loop you used `"%d"` in your `printf` instead of `%s`. If you change the point where the error happens, it will confuse people trying to answer the question.

Comment: I misdirected you, `printf("%d", number);` might help, with`atoi` like in @DanielH 's answer.

Comment: Are you trying to print `line` as shown in `printf("%s", line);` outside the while or trying to print  `number`?

Comment: trying to print number actually my bad!

Comment: Ive edited the code so it's printing the number, sorry all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion comes from printing `line` within the loop and then attempting to print `number` after the loop. `line` is type `char[256]` which on access is converted to simple `char*`. `number` is type `int`. You cannot assign `char*` to `int`.

In order to convert the ASCII digits in `line` to an integer `number` you can use `sscanf` (appropriate in this context) or you can use `strtol` (or you can manually convert it with modulo and division).

Here you correctly read a line of input with the *line-oriented* input function `fgets` (that's good). You simply need to convert the ASCII digits in `line` to an integer. You can do that with `sscanf`, for example:

```
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        i++;
        if (i == 3) {
            if (sscanf (line, "%d", &number) != 1) {
                fputs ("error: no integer at start of line 3\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            printf ("number inside loop : %d\n", number);
            break;  /* no reason to read further */
        }
    }
```

(**note:** the validation of the conversion with `sscanf` by checking the return against the number of conversions requested -- validate every read or conversion)

Note, do not *hardcode* filenames or numbers. `main()` takes arguments, `argc` holds the argument count present (there will always be at least `1` argument, the name of the executable), and `argv` is your argument vector (an array of pointers to each argument with the next pointer after the last argument set to `NULL`) Pass your filename to your program as an argument. You can also conditionally set your program to read from the filename provided as the first argument, or from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided.

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    /* read from file given as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE* file = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    char line[256];
    int number = 0,  /* initialize number - what if you have a 2-line file */
        i = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        i++;
        if (i == 3) {
            if (sscanf (line, "%d", &number) != 1) {
                fputs ("error: no integer at start of line 3\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            printf ("number inside loop : %d\n", number);
            break;  /* no reason to read further */
        }
    }
    fclose(file);   /* close file - read operations done */

    if (i == 3)     /* validate 3 lines read from file */
        printf ("number outside loop: %d\n", number);
    else
        fputs ("error: less than 3-lines in file.\n", stderr);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/3line.txt
10
20
38
40
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readline3 dat/3line.txt
number inside loop : 38
number outside loop: 38
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information, Really appreciate this, I'm new to C so it's good to have things explained well!

Comment: We all started from the same place. There is a lot to learn with C, so slow down, pay attention to the details, validate everything and enjoy learning a fantastic language. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop keep running even after your first print. And the `char` array `line` keeps updating in the line `gets(line, sizeof(line), file)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    FILE *file = fopen("blocks.txt", "r");
    char line[256];
    long int number;
    int i = 0;
    char *stopped;

    /*keeps updating line till fget returns a failed response*/
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        i++;
        if (i == 3)
        {
            number = (int)strtol(line, &stopped, 10);
            if (!*stopped)
            { /* handle error */
                printf("Error in strtol\n");
                return -1;
            }
            //prints 38
            printf("%s", line);
        }
    }
    /*Once the while loop ends it will have the last 
    line of the file block.txt*/
    printf("%ld", number);
    fclose(file);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**caveat for atoi**

We could have used **atoi**. But`atoi` isn't safe and can lead to many careless errors. See [link](http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_atoi.aspx). You should be using `strtol` which will convert a string to a `long int`.

Comment: Hmm, why was `number = line` ignored?

Comment: @jackw11111 I removed it because it was not used. I usually compile `all warnings pedantic`

Comment: Okay, that is true. But the question, albeit ambiguously worded, seems to be asking about assigning an `int` inside a `while` loop and trying to access the same variable outside the loop.

Comment: @jackw11111 Is he trying to print `line` outside the while or `number`. My answer is for `line`.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the type of a variable is important. The type of `line` is `char[256]`, meaning it's an array of 256 characters, which in this case is more than enough to hold the length of the line.

However, `number` is an `int`. C tries hard to convert the types in a reasonable way, but its definition of "reasonable" is not yours. It stores the *address where `line` is found in memory* into `number`. Then, in `printf` inside the while loop, you tell it to print using `"%s"`, meaning "treat this as though it's the address of a bunch of characters in memory", which it turns out to be, so it works.

Outside the while loop, you use `"%d"`, which says "print this as though it's a number". Technically, it is a number, but it's not the number 38; it's a number which has no meaning to you and not that much meaning to even people who are experts in C.

To fix this, you need to actually convert the string to a number (if you want to do math on it), or just store it as text and never pretend it's a number. To convert it to a number, use [`atoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi).

You should enable warnings on your compiler so it'll tell you if you're doing this sort of thing in the future. Depending on how you're compiling, you can change some settings in your IDE (like Visual Studio or Eclipse) or you can add something to the compiler command line, such as using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` instead of just `gcc`.